# Accidentally deleted LVM on raid partition

Tags: raid, lvm, gparted, rescue-disk

I accidentally deleted my LVM partition inside /dev/md1. The good thing that my linux root partition and swap inside this LVM are still mounted. I was able to copy all data to my backup HDD, and was able to do a dd copy of my LVM root partition.

Now gparted on /dev/md1 shows that all space is unlocated. If I reboot my pc I will loose ability to boot it again.
Is there any way to quickly recover partition table without reinstalling system? Keep in mind that LVM still knows the partition table, I am able to read and write to that non-existent partitions.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/LVM/recovery_of_lvm_partitions.shtml maybe this will help. And this http://www.barryodonovan.com/2007/12/08/lvm-recovery

Comment: You also could try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which can find old partitions and rewrite the partition table.